# Description of return type

Tags: c#

I do not understand the return type... I am a VB developer. is it returning some array???

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static object GetUploadStatus()
{
    //Get the length of the file on disk and divide that by the length of the stream
    UploadDetail info = (UploadDetail)HttpContext.Current.Session["UploadDetail"];
    if (info != null && info.IsReady)
    {
        int soFar = info.UploadedLength;
        int total = info.ContentLength;
        int percentComplete = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)soFar / (double)total * 100);
        string message = "Uploading...";
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}", info.FileName);
        string downloadBytes = string.Format("{0} of {1} Bytes", soFar, total);
        return new {
                percentComplete = percentComplete,
                message = message,
                fileName = fileName,
                downloadBytes = downloadBytes};
    }
    //Not ready yet
    return null;
}
```

thank you

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx - Anonymous Types

Comment: try http://converter.telerik.com/ to get a preliminary translation (In this case the translation looks good)

Comment: Thanks @Bala its a good tool..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is returning an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) (VB.NET reference). It is a type that has no corresponding class.

> Visual Basic supports anonymous types, which enable you to create objects without writing a class definition for the data type. Instead, the compiler generates a class for you. The class has no usable name, inherits directly from Object, and contains the properties you specify in declaring the object. Because the name of the data type is not specified, it is referred to as an anonymous type.

Answer (score 3):

No its returning an anonymous type.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning an [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

It's basically like creating a class on the fly.

Every value on the left side of an equation-mark is a property-name.

Answer (score 1):

That's returning an anonymous type (not an array) with the following properties: percentComplete, message, fileName, and downloadBytes.

Answer (score 1):

converted to VB might help you:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod> _
Public Shared Function GetUploadStatus() As Object
    Dim info As UploadDetail = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Session("UploadDetail"), UploadDetail)
    If info IsNot Nothing AndAlso info.IsReady Then
        Dim soFar As Integer = info.UploadedLength
        Dim total As Integer = info.ContentLength
        Dim percentComplete As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(CDbl(soFar) / CDbl(total) * 100))
        Dim message As String = "Uploading..."
        Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}", info.FileName)
        Dim downloadBytes As String = String.Format("{0} of {1} Bytes", soFar, total)
        Return New With { _
            Key .percentComplete = percentComplete, _
            Key .message = message, _
            Key .fileName = fileName, _
            Key .downloadBytes = downloadBytes _
        }
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Unlikely that will help someone who doesn't know what anonymous initializers are. Even in VB.NET, they use some kind of weird-looking, curly-brace syntax... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's returning an anonymous instance with attributes percentComplete, message, fileName  and downloadBytes . The caller would have to use reflection to access the properties (or use `dynamic` keyword in .NET 4).

An easier thing to would be to create a class with these properties and return an instance of that type rather than the anonymous type to avoid using reflection.

Comment: Actually you can use the "Cast By Example" trick to read an instance of anonymous type if the object is being read *in the same assembly as it was created*, and avoid reflection or dynamic. However, if you're doing this inside the same assembly, then why not just make an internal nominal type?

Answer (score 0):

It's returning an object with some named properties. Or null if `//Not ready yet`